# Windows 7 phantom removable disk

Tags: windows-7, removable-media

I have a strange symptom with in Windows 7: the `D:` removable disk in the screenshot below doesn't exist, if you click on it, it says 'Please insert disk'. You can't eject it, and it's not related to the other (E:) disk, added here simply for comparison.

Any ideas what this could be?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have a device that has the ability to have removable media placed in it.  I have a printer that supports something like this, and I have a similar, removable disk on my system I just ignore it.  **You can confirm this by removing all devices connected to your system except your keyboard and mouse.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a card reader?  What is generally occurring when you see this is that there is a controller that shows as a drive even when no media is present.  One of my 4 in one card readers does this with 4 removable drives that show up as letters but have no disk until I insert a card.

Comment: One of my card readers does this too, which is why the "Hide empty drives" option in Explorer is so useful. :)

Comment: @Karan - nice, I learned something today, good to know.  Granted, I'm a die hard Total Commander user since Windows 3.0, so I use Explorer just about never.